# How to delete node in double linked list correctly?

Tags: c++, list, pointers, nodes

```
void SinglyLinkedList::removeBike(int c)
{
   Node* current = head;

   for(int i = 0; i < c; i++){         // traverse to desired node
       current = current -> next;
   } 

   if(current -> next != NULL && current -> prev != NULL){
        current -> prev -> next = current -> next;
        current -> next -> prev = current -> prev;
        delete current;                     //delete node
   }
   else if(current -> next == NULL){
      current -> prev -> next = current;
      delete current;
   }
   else if(current -> prev == NULL){
       current -> next -> prev = current;
       delete current;
   }    
   else 
       cout << "How did you make it this far?";

}
```

I'm fairly certain I'm not understanding something here, but research hasn't helped so far.

Logically it makes sense to me but I feel like this is too simple to work, which it isn't.

edited: updated the code minus input check and it breaks on me when I input any int. also I should probably rename the class to doubly linked list... just noticed that

Comment: Best way I've ever seen to figure out linked lists is draw the nodes on a piece of paper and then draw in all of the changes in linkage required step by step.

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i < c; i++){` should be `for(int i = 0; i < c || current != NULL; i++){`.

Comment: && current != NULL works much better, for me... And then you'll have to figure out what to do when you wind up with a NULL current, after the loop.

Comment: _@Josh_ Stop editing your question with tries to fix the code. Don't create moving targets that invalidate present answers. That's not useful.

Comment: its breaking on me on the first line of the first if statement. done with edits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope, it's definitely not that simple.

First of all if the `c` parameter exceeds the size of the list, you'll blow up with a null pointer dereference, as your `current` pointer hits the null pointer on the last node, and blows past it.

Then, if `c` is 0 or the index of the last element of the list, either it's `prev` or it's `next` pointer, accordingly, will be null, and you'll also blow up with a null pointer dereference.

```
current -> prev -> next = current -> next;
current -> next -> prev = current -> prev;
```

If `current` is the first element in the list, `current->prev` will obviously null. If `current` is the last element in the list, `current->next` will obviously be null. Guess what happens when you attempt to dereference the null pointer?

Conclusions:

A) Check that the input parameter to the function is valid.

B) Provide for special handling when the node to be deleted is the first or the last node in the doubly-linked list.

EDIT: by popular request, someone wanted to know how I would fix this:

```
void SinglyLinkedList::removeBike(int c)
{
   Node* current = head;

   for(int i = 0; i < c; i++){
       if (!current)
           break;
       current = current -> next;
   } 

   if (!current)
           return; // Or throw an exception. Or return a bool false, maybe.

   if (current->prev)
       current -> prev -> next = current -> next;
   else
       head=current->next;

   if (current->next)
       current -> next -> prev = current -> prev;
   else
       tail=current->prev;  // Assuming that there's a tail, somewhere around here...
   delete current;                      //delete node

   // Maybe "return true;" here...
}
```

Comment: AH dunno how I messed it up that much. didnt even think about the first or last being the desired one. wow. appreciate the input! well i'll edit if I have further issues after ive done that.

Comment: No, no need to take this down. This is a valid question.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik A completely fixed code sample of the `SinglyLinkedList::removeBike()` function would be great at least.

Comment: _"by popular request"_ I didn't recognize I'm such a _popular person_ so far :-P, but THX. Though a nitpick _`// Maybe "return true;" here...`_ The function return type is `void` actually.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I think the `return true` was a suggestion, you would change the function signature. I agree as well, its nice to know if it has been removed or not.

Comment: Yes, it was a suggestion. I plopped down a "return false", also commented out, up top.

Comment: this had a runtime error at the second if statement.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. Maybe if more details were provided, about this mysterious error, perhaps some further progress would've been possible. Otherwise, the chances are no better than the chances would be of me calling my auto mechanic, telling him that "my car doesn't work", and expect to get a useful diagnosis solely based on that.

Comment: I appreciate the help. evidently the problem is more deeply rooted than the function itself so I'll try and figure it out and make a new post later on once I feel this is the only problem left with the program. thanks!

Comment: @JoshPeel Remember to mark this answer correct if it solved your problem (which it should have).