# Trouble adding to back of doubly linked list

Tags: c++, list, doubly-linked-list

```
void DoublyLinkedList::addFront(const Bike& e) 
{   

Node* temp = new Node;                      // Create new node.
temp->bike = e;                             // Store data.
temp->next = head;
temp->prev = NULL;                          // Current head is now next of our new node.
head->prev = temp;
head = temp;                                // Our new node is now the new head.
}

void DoublyLinkedList::addBack(const Bike& e) 
{   

Node* temp = new Node;          // Create new node
temp -> bike = e;
temp -> next = NULL;
temp -> prev = tail;            // our new nodes prev is now the tail
tail -> next = temp;
tail = temp;                    // the tail equals the new node                                 
}
```

my add front method works just fine but the addBack method doesnt fail, however when i display the list, there is no new node being displayed like there is with add front.

any idea what could be causing this? im lost

edit: updated code to include suggestion

Comment: Is that related to [How to delete node in double linked list correctly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35566363/how-to-delete-node-in-double-linked-list-correctly) somehow?

Comment: it has to be somehow. im having trouble with the tail/prev aspect of this list

Comment: `addFront` does *not* work just fine. If you go backwards through the list, you won't find the nodes added by `addFront`.

Comment: Thank you! i see the mistake now.

Comment: There's not enough code shown to really answer this question. I am puzzled by the fact that you're method is called SinglyLinkedList and is quite plainly doubly. The code looks right from just a quick look, but I need to see what head and tail are.

Comment: i just spent a second updating the class names. it was originally singly linked but I misunderstood the fact that it was supposed to be doubly linked

Comment: @JoshPeel Do not update your question with answers. Instead, add your own answer.

Comment: still pretty new. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You correctly initialized the new node's `next` and `prev` pointers, where appropriate.

However, when adding to the head of a nonempty list, you forgot to set the former head node's `prev` pointer to the new node at the head of the list; and when adding to the tail of a nonempty list, you forgot to set the former tail node's `next` pointer to the new node at the tail of the list.

Answer (score 0):

Code that ended up working for me was

```
  void DoublyLinkedList::addFront(const Bike& e) 
 {  
 if(empty()){
    Node* temp = new Node;                      // Create new node.
    temp->bike = e;                             // Store data.
    temp->next = head;                          // Current head is now next of our new node.
    temp->prev = head;
    head = temp; 
    tail = temp;
    quantity++;
}
else{
    Node* temp = new Node;
    temp -> bike = e;
    temp -> next = head;
    temp -> next -> prev = temp;
    temp -> prev = NULL;
    head = temp;
    quantity++;
}
}


void DoublyLinkedList::addBack(const Bike& e) 
{   
Node* temp = new Node;          // Create new node
temp -> bike = e;
temp -> prev = tail;            // our new nodes prev is now the tail
temp -> prev -> next = temp;
temp -> next = NULL;
tail = temp;                    // the tail equals the new node 
quantity++;
}
```